# Need to call a function on button click

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.0

I need to print log info when a button is clicked. I am using the below code, please let me know what are the mistakes in my code. I am trying to call a function like below.

'on_click' => 'execute();',

**Button.php**

```
<?php
namespace Dss\CoveoSearch\Block\System\Config;
use Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement;
class Button extends Field
{
    protected $_template = 'Dss_CoveoSearch::system/config/button.phtml';
    protected $_logger;
    public function __construct(\Dss\CoveoSearch\Logger\Logger $logger, Context $context, array $data = [])
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->_logger = $logger;
    }

    public function render(AbstractElement $element)
    {
        $element->unsScope()->unsCanUseWebsiteValue()->unsCanUseDefaultValue();
        return parent::render($element);
    }
    protected function _getElementHtml(AbstractElement $element)
    {
        return $this->_toHtml();
    }
    public function getCustomUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('hello');
    }
    public function hello()
    {
        $test = 'hello';
        echo $test;
    }
    public function execute()
    {
        $this->_logger->info('Hello This is our Custom log file example');
    }
    public function getButtonHtml()
    {
        $button = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Button')->setData(['id' => 'btn_id', 'label' => __('Create'),'on_click' => 'execute();',]);
        return $button->toHtml();
        
    }
}
```

**button.phtml**

```
<?php
    $controller = $block->getCustomUrl();
    echo $block->hello();
    echo $block->getButtonHtml();
?>
```

Comment: What's the error you're encountering?

Comment: not getting any error but the info is not printing in the log.

Comment: `echo $block->hello();` is this working? Did you try echoing something instead of logging on button click?

Comment: yes, this is working. If I try to echo something then it is displaying near to button.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this for an Ajax call and it's working like a charm. See if this could help.

```
public function getButtonHtml()
    {
        $button = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
            'Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Button'
        )->setData(
            [
                'id' => 'clear_button',
                'label' => __('Clear'),
                'on_click' => sprintf("location.href = '%s';", $this->getAjaxUrl()),
            ]
        );

        return $button->toHtml();
    }

public function getAjaxUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('vendor_module/system_config/ClearCtrl');
    }
```